Tkinter python program seem to work without a mainloop, why?
With this small PYTHON code:
import time
def toto(num=-1):
    for i in range(10):
        print ('toto:',num,' :: loop:',i,flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)


app=tk.Tk()#bg='black')
app.geometry('+600+600')
tk.Button(app,text='MAIN_BUTTON1',command=lambda a=-1: toto(a)).grid()
print ("APP=",app)
"""app2=tk.Tk()#bg='black')
app2.geometry('+300+300')
tk.Button(app2,text='MAIN_BUTTON2',command=lambda a=-2: toto(a)).grid()
print ("APP2=",app2)"""

input()

When i run it in a linux KDE Konsole terminal, i can press the 'MAIN_BUTTON1' and activate toto function. It seem like the standard input() function while waiting keyboard input permit Ui event to be executed by ????
is anyone have an idea. Perhaps this only happen inside linux and KDE?
I just use input with the goal to step(block) the entire program for debugging purpose. The effect is strange for me, but i am not a professional.

If input() is being provided by the readline module (this is standard when running Python directly in a terminal, but not in an IDE), that module has an "input hook" feature that allows external code to run every time input is requested.  tkinter uses this hook to process events, even in the absence of a running mainloop() - at least until the first keypress, which causes the hook to exit, so that actual input can take place.

root.mainloop() runs indefinitely until the window is closed. input() waits until the user inputs something.
In this way, Both root.mainloop() and input() are blocking calls. meaning: they prevent further code execution until they are finished.
input() can make the Tkinter window responsive for a short period (until the user provides input). It is just an incidental behaviour and it is not a substitute for root.mainloop().

im new in tkinter, but i think it probably just accepts because there's only one widget (the button in this case), but when you try to specify with app.geometry being 600x600 the program doesn't work.
